# Track panel identifier name changes over time

Tags: stata, recode

I have a panel identifier that is a firm's name stored as an alphanumeric code and I would like to track name changes throughout the panel. For example, firm A is renamed to B on on May 25, 2001. Then firm B is renamed to C on May 25, 2003. Then firm C is renamed to D on May 25, 2005. In this example firms D, E, and G are not renamed.

I want a "transition matrix" so that I can see if firm A is involved in some transaction at a later date under a new name. For example, in the first row of the test data firms A and G are involved in a transaction announced on Aug 12, 2001. The `AA` variable is determined long in the past, so by the time that Aug 12, 2001 rolls around `AA`'s new firm name is B (change occurred on May 25, 2001). In the second row of the test data B and H are involved in a transaction also announced on Aug 12, 2001. But `AA` has not had time to change again so the firm's name is still B.

The code below tracks these name changes, but I am suspicious that this approach is too mechanical and not robust to scenarios that I haven't yet considered.

Is there a more logical approach that I should follow or a command that handles this re-coding?

```
* data on re-coding
clear
input str1 OldCode str1 NewCode str8 Date
A B 20010525
B C 20030525
C D 20050525
D   
E   
F G 20010525
G   
end 

generate temp = date(Date, "YMD")
drop Date
rename temp Date
format Date %td

* save to temp file
preserve
tempfile Codes
save "`Codes'"
restore

* merge back (recursively) to generate wide data that track re-coding
local i = 0
local j = 1

while (`j' != 0) {
    local ++i
    rename OldCode OldCode`i'
    rename NewCode NewCode`i'
    rename Date Date`i'

    cross using "`Codes'"
    count if (NewCode`i' == OldCode)
    local j = `r(N)' // zero when all re-codings accounted for
    keep if (NewCode`i' == OldCode) | missing(NewCode`i')
    replace OldCode = "" if missing(NewCode`i')
    replace NewCode = "" if missing(NewCode`i')
    replace Date = . if missing(NewCode`i')

    duplicates drop
}

* last addition is unnecessary 
drop OldCode NewCode Date

* rename and sort, only need first code
rename OldCode1 temp
drop OldCode*
rename temp OldCode
sort OldCode

* reshape to long
reshape long NewCode Date, i(OldCode)
drop _j
duplicates drop
compress
save "Codes", replace

* test data
clear
input str1 AA str1 TA str8 Date
A G 20010812
B H 20010812
C D 20050812
end
generate DealNumber = _n

generate temp = date(Date, "YMD")
drop Date
rename temp DateAnnounced
format DateAnnounced %td

clonevar OldCode = AA
joinby OldCode using "Codes.dta", unmatched(master)
drop _merge

sort DealNumber Date 
keep if (DateAnnounced >= Date) | missing(Date)
bysort DealNumber (Date) : keep if (_n == 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a firm identifier that groups all observations of the same firm under different names. This is pretty straightforward to do with `group_id` (from SSC). Something like:

```
* data on re-coding
clear
input str1 OldCode str1 NewCode str8 Date
A B 20010525
B C 20030525
C D 20050525
D   
E   
F G 20010525
G
J C 20011525
end 

* convert dyads to long form
gen dyad_id = _n
expand 2 if !mi(NewCode)
bysort dyad_id: gen code = cond(_n == 1, OldCode, NewCode)

* use -group_id- (from SSC) to further group dyad_id when code is the same
clonevar jointcode = dyad_id
group_id jointcode, match(code)

* revert to the original wide form
drop code
bysort jointcode dyad_id: keep if _n == 1
list, sepby(jointcode)
```